# How to Model Ternary Relationship in CakePhp?

Tags: database, cakephp

Page table 
(1) 
| 
| 
(*) 
User_Moderate_Page (*)----------- (1)Access_level table 
(*) 
| 
| 
(1) 
User table

How do i Model such a ternary relationship in CakePhp?
User to Page can be modelled using the hasBelongtoMany Relationship. But User_Moderate_page is just an association table, should I even write a Model for User_Moderate_Page in Cake?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure CakePHP accepts this, but what you should do is create the table with a primary key and the 3 foreign keys. Somewhat like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`access_levels_pages_users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `page_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `access_level_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_access_levels_pages_users_pages` (`page_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_access_levels_pages_users_access_levels1` (`access_level_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_access_levels_pages_users_users1` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_access_levels_pages_users_pages`
    FOREIGN KEY (`page_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`pages` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_access_levels_pages_users_access_levels1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`access_level_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`access_levels` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_access_levels_pages_users_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Now, I'm not sure Cake will bake this table, so you might have to try and make the models by hand, this table would have belongsTo the 3 other tables. The other 3 tables non association tables will have to have a HMABTM relationship with the other 2, as in users HMABTM access_levels and pages and so on.

Again, not sure if it will work. I would suggest maybe trying to see if you can model it in a different manner.

Answer (score 1):

Let me generalize it by describing it with generic tables:
Lets say you have 3 tables - firsts, seconds, thirds - each with primary keys 'id'.

let your join table be called 'firsts_seconds_thirds' with foreign keys to each main table:

- first_id
- second_id
- third_id
- <additional fields of this association table>

usually we define HABTM relationships between tables, in this case we need to create a cake model for the join table - lets call it **FirstsSecondsThird** (By cakePhp's naming conventions)

The relationship between models you need to define is:

- First **hasMany** FirstsSecondsThird
- Second **hasMany** FirstsSecondsThird
- Third **hasMany** FirstsSecondsThird
- FirstsSecondsThird **belongsTo** First,Second,Third

The need for this is explained here - Associations: [Linking Models Together](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through)
Code for the same:

```
class First extends AppModel {    
    public $hasMany = array(
        'FirstsSecondsThird'  => array(
            'className' => 'FirstsSecondsThird',
            'foreignKey' => 'first_id'
        )
    );
}

//Same for classes 'Second' and 'Third'

class FirstsSecondsThird extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'First' => array(
            'className' => 'First',
            'foreignKey' => 'first_id'
        ),
        'Second' => array(
            'className' => 'Second',
            'foreignKey' => 'second_id'
        ),
        'Third' => array(
            'className' => 'Third',
            'foreignKey' => 'third_id'
        )
    );
}
```

The models are perfectly setup, but now inserting/updating/deleting from the main/join table should be done correctly or they are of no use.
`Model::saveMany()` and `Model::saveAssociated()`, using the option 'deep' etc. need to be used. Read about it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array). 
You also need to think about ON DELETE RESTRICT/CASCADE for these join tables and model them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Look up ACL. It is complicated, but it is what you need (especially if you need the flexibility in setting up who can moderate what page)