# CakePHP .find to return multiple HABTM relationships

Tags: cakephp

I have a Model call Playlist.
Playlist has a HABTM with Track

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Track' => array(
        'className' => 'Track',
        'joinTable' => 'tracklists_tracks',
        'foreignKey' => 'tracklist_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'track_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => array('id','title','version'),
        'order' => 'TracklistsTrack.timing'
    )
);
```

Track has an HABTM with AppUser

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Artist' => array(
        'className' => 'AppUser',
        'joinTable' => 'artists_tracks',
        'foreignKey' => 'track_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'artist_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => array('id','username') 
    )
);
```

Now, i would like, when i write this

$tracklist = $this->Tracklist->findById($id);

to get for each tracklist all the tracks (and this does work as supposed to), and for every tracks all the AppUsers (cascading).

Mind that if i write $this->Track->findById($id);
i can actually get the AppUsers related to the track

Any idea to have this out of the box thanks to my diligent naming convention ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please write Both model? I am lilbit confused with AppUser and Artist.

Comment: Suggestion : Usually you should convert your HABTMs to hasMany like a join model for much better flexibility. habtms get very unmanageable, you can read this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#what-to-do-when-habtm-becomes-complicated

Comment: Sure, so Artist is just an alias that i use for AppUser, since a tracks will have Artists but also Remixers that are both AppUsers.

Comment: @Ankan-Zerob i guess that's a great best practice, so i should break up a HABTM into 2 hasMany on both size? as a database there should still be a 3rd table that has the 2 main table id's as foreign keys. Is that correct?

Comment: consider tables : firsts habtm seconds and the join table is firsts_seconds. Your models will be First, Second and FirstsSecond respectively. First hasMany FirstsSecond, Second hasMany FirstsSecond, FirstsSecond belongsTo First, Second.

Comment: use containable after these associations, and retrieving and saving data for complicated joins become damn simple. also make sure your db deisgn is good and you are not looking for a ternary relationship - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252082/how-to-model-ternary-relationship-in-cakephp/21789822#21789822

Comment: Hey @Ankan-Zerob really clear explanation! was not 100% with using a join model, but i guess in the long run is the best choice! Thanks for the pointers as well

Comment: Need some more help here. When i try this, it still doesn't execute the join. (Producer is the join model) $tracks = $this->Track->find('all',array('contain' => array('Producer', 'AppUser')));

Answer (score 0):

If you have define the correct relationship in your model, I would suggest using CakePHP containable behavior.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

All you need to do is to include the behavior in your model and put the following in your controller

```
$this->TrackList->contain(array('AppUser','Artist'));
```